# Retrieving multiple versions of source code for a file

Tags: java, error-handling

I have the following code that checks for three different properties. Unfortunately each call can throw up to four exceptions that I all have to catch. Can I some how make the code more readable by reducing the amount of try/catch?

```
public void retrieveSourceCode() {
        try {
            fileName = RestServices.getInstance().getClassName(getSourceCodeURI()); 
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            fileName = "not available";
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            fileName = "not available";
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RestServicesException e) {
            fileName = "not available";
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (!(fileName.endsWith(".jar") || fileName.endsWith(".svn-base"))) {
            try {
                sourceCode = RestServices.getInstance().sendGetRequestJsonTextToString(getSourceCodeURI());
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                sourceCode = "not available";
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                sourceCode = "not available";
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (RestServicesException e) {
                sourceCode = "not available";
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (before == null) {
                beforeSourceCode = "no before source code available";
            } else {
                try {
                    beforeSourceCode = RestServices.getInstance().sendGetRequestJsonTextToString(getBeforeVersionURI());
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    beforeSourceCode = "no before source code available";
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    beforeSourceCode = "no before source code available";
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (RestServicesException e) {
                    beforeSourceCode = "no before source code available";
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (after == null) {
                afterSourceCode = "no after source code available";
            } else {
                try {
                    afterSourceCode = RestServices.getInstance().sendGetRequestJsonTextToString(getAfterVersionURI());
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    afterSourceCode = "no after source code available";
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    afterSourceCode = "no after source code available";
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (RestServicesException e) {
                    afterSourceCode = "no after source code available";
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        getChangeSet().addAffectedFile(getFileName());

    }
```

Comment: Someone should of pointed out that ClientProtocolException is an IOException making catching ClientProtocolException pointless in this code.

Comment: You may not have control over it, but needing to check "before" and "after" for null is a little smelly to me.

Answer (score 18):

If you upgrade to Java 7, you can use the new Multi-catch syntax. You could change the first block to:

```
    try {
        fileName = RestServices.getInstance().getClassName(getSourceCodeURI()); 
    } catch (ClientProtocolException | IOException | RestServicesException e) {
        fileName = "not available";
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Essentially if there are many exceptions you catch and handle in the same way, you can use multi-catch

Comment: That's rather nifty. C# needs this. A lot.

Answer (score 12):

These unhandled exceptions [smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) very bad. Storing error messages in the place of data also is not a good sign (like `fileName = "not available"`).

Anyway, some notes:

1. You could extract out a

   ```
   RestServices restServices = RestServices.getInstance();
   ```

   variable.
2. You should create constants from repeating Strings, like `"not available"`, `"no before source code available"` etc.
3. I'd extract out `getFileName` method for the first `try-catch` block, a `getSourceCode` for the second, and so on.

Comment: Agreed - What's the point of catching an exception if you don't deal with it?

Answer (score 5):

A `try` and `catch` block should be in their own method so as not to interrupt logic in another method.

```
private void getClassName(T URI, String error){
    T2 className;
    try{
        className = RestServices.getInstance().getClassName(URI);
    } catch (Exception e){
        className = error;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        return className;
    }
}
```

and

```
private void sendGetRequestJsonTextToString(T URI, String error){
    T2 reply;
    try {
        reply = RestServices.getInstance().sendGetRequestJsonTextToString(URI));
    } catch(Exception e){
        reply = error;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        return reply;
    }
}
```

This method now has no `try-catch` block interrupting the logic. Also, [guard clause](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuardClause) can be used in place of nested `if`s.

```
public void retrieveSourceCode(){
    String error;
    error = "not available";
    filename = getClassName(getSourceCodeURI(), error);

    // this conditional can be extracted to a method, giving more readability
    // say, if(!isSourcecode(filename))
    if(fileName.endsWith(".jar") || !fileName.endsWith(".svn-base"))){
        return;
    }

    error = "not available";
    sourceCode = sendGetRequestJsonTextToString(getSourceCodeURI(), error);


    error = "no before source code available";
    if(before == null){
        beforeSourceCode = error;
    } else {
        beforeSourceCode = sendGetRequestJsonTextToString(getBeforeVersionURI(), error);
    }


    error = "no after source code available";
    if(after == null){
        afterSourceCode = error;
    } else {
        afterSourceCode = sendGetRequestJsonTextToString(getAfterVersionURI(), error);
    }


    getChangeSet().addAffectedFile(getFileName());
}
```

This still has some [smells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) (as mentioned in another answer), but it does what the questions asking for: to simplify the `try-catch` block.

Comment: You've declared `getClassName` and `sendGetRequestJsonTextToString` as `void`, but then `return` values from them.

Answer (score 3):

Considering that you do literally the exact same thing regardless of the type of exception, you can cut down the catch statements by catching type `Exception` instead of a specific subclass:

```
public void retrieveSourceCode() {
    try {
        fileName = RestServices.getInstance().getClassName(getSourceCodeURI());    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fileName = "not available";
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (!(fileName.endsWith(".jar") || fileName.endsWith(".svn-base"))) {
        try {
            sourceCode = RestServices.getInstance().sendGetRequestJsonTextToString(getSourceCodeURI());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            sourceCode = "not available";
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        if (before == null) {
            beforeSourceCode = "no before source code available";
        } else {
            try {
                beforeSourceCode = RestServices.getInstance().sendGetRequestJsonTextToString(getBeforeVersionURI());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                beforeSourceCode = "no before source code available";
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }

        if (after == null) {
            afterSourceCode = "no after source code available";
        } else {
            try {
                afterSourceCode = RestServices.getInstance().sendGetRequestJsonTextToString(getAfterVersionURI());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                afterSourceCode = "no after source code available";
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    }
    getChangeSet().addAffectedFile(getFileName());
}
```

Comment: But keep in mind that this will also catch unchecked RuntimeExceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 syntax wins.

For Java < 7, catching the `Exception` base class works but it's unfortunate to stop unrelated exceptions from propagating. Here's a workaround to consider:

```
String getFileName() {
  try {
    return RestServices.getInstance().getClassName(getSourceCodeURI());
  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
  } catch (IOException e) {
  } catch (RestServicesException) {
  }
  return "not available";
}
```

Comment: Note that you'll lose the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `if` statement inside your `catch`. It could get ugly if you're trying to catch a lot of different exception types but it should be fine for a handful. Sorry for any errors in my syntax. It's been a while since I've used Java.

```
try {
    fileName = RestServices.getInstance().getClassName(getSourceCodeURI());  
}catch (Exception e){
    if (e instanceof ClientProtocolException || e instanceof IOException || e instanceof RestServicesException) {
        fileName = "not available";
        e.printStackTrace();
    }else{
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I'm glad you post an answer and hope you'll stay around. I'm not a big fan of this approach, this should get the job done, but is a lot of "boiler" plate IMHO.

Comment: I mostly agree, hence why I'd only use it with a small number of exceptions. Otherwise multiple catch blocks is probably the way to go, although it looks like the latest Java version has solved this problem.